# How to deal with user options and mysql database

Tags: mysql, regex, database-design

I'm writing a PHP program. Each content has some options which stores users preferences. For example:

- Where the content should be shown in the template?
- In which categories or pages, the content should be loaded?

Now, I store these data in a single field named `options` as JSON. the final result is something like:

```
{
    "locales":["en"],
    "themes":{
        "default":{
            "width":"0",
            "height":"0",
            "top":"0",
            "right":"0",
            "bottom":"0",
            "left":"0"
        }
    },
    "pages":["aboutus\/"],
    "categories":["all"],
    "homepage":"false"
}
```

I have no problem to select data and filter rows using mysql regexp statement. But I have 3 other questions:

1. How to update a JSON field value in a single update statement?
2. Does it make sense to do such a trick at all (I mean using JSON)?
3. What other solutions do you recommend to store options, while there a lots of property to be stored?

Comment: IMO, 2 & 3 are a little OT for SO

Comment: @Strawberry Hey buddy, I'm new to this site. what do you mean by OT & SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no absolute way to do that in none-NoSQL database like MySQL. However, not exactly for JSON, you can see [how FriendFeed uses MySQL to store schema-less data](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql) and it may give you some ideas.

**UPDATE:**
MySQL 5.7.8 and newer versions are now supporting JSON data type. There are some [tutorials](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql) to help.